# Facebook - JavaScript login

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

How to retrieve data from the profile using JavaScript from Facebook in the database?

Is it possible to retrieve data using only JavaScript? Perhaps using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get all information available to the Graph API via the Facebook Javascript SDK.  See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
});
FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=me()'
  },
  function(response) {
    alert('Your name is ' + response[0].name);
  }
);
```